# Split long lines into separate lines of max length after a certain line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have big files with long base64 strings (after line 112). Some of the first 112 lines are longer than 80 characters and I want to keep it like that. I only want to split all lines after line 112 to max 80 characters.

In this example I only want to split all lines after line 5 to max 80 characters:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
rcitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip e
rcitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip e
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
```

Expected output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
rcitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip e
rcitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip e
TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdCwgc2Vk
IGRvIGVpdXNtb2QgdGVtcG9yIGluY2lkaWR1bnQgdXQgbGFib3JlIGV0IGRvbG9yZSBtYWduYSBhbGlx
WEuIFV0IGVuaW0gYWQgbWluaW0gdmVuaWFtLCBxdWlzIG5vc3RydWQgZXhlcmNpdGF0aW9uIHVsbGFtY
28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0IGFsaXF1aXAgZXggZWEgY29tbW9kbyBjb25zZXF1YXQuIER1aXMgYXV0Z
SBpcnVyZSBkb2xvciBpbiByZXByZWhlbmRlcml0IGluIHZvbHVwdGF0ZSB2ZWxpdCBlc3NlIGNpbGx1b
SBkb2xvcmUgZXUgZnVnaWF0IG51bGxhIHBhcmlhdHVyLiBFeGNlcHRldXIgc2ludCBvY2NhZWNhdCBjd
XBpZGF0YXQgbm9uIHByb2lkZW50LCBzdW50IGluIGN1bHBhIHF1aSBvZmZpY2lhIGRlc2VydW50IG1vb
GxpdCBhbmltIGlkIGVzdCBsYWJvcnVtLg0KcmNpdGF0aW9uIHVsbGFtY28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0I
GFsaXF1aXAgZQ0KcmNpdGF0aW9uIHVsbGFtY28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0IGFsaXF1aXAgZQ==
```

I know how to ignore lines with sed but not how to set a maximum char limit and split the lines with. When I search on the internet people recommend fold

```
fold -w80 input.txt
```

But with fold I can't ignore lines? Any idea how to do this with fold or sed? Maybe awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed you can do, and add a `-i` if you need to apply the changes to `input.txt` (if your file contains line that are 80 charactere longs exactly this will add a blanc line after it) :

```
sed -E 's/(.{80})/\1\n/g' input.txt
```

In your case if you only need that after the line 112 :

```
sed -E '113,$s/(.{80})/\1\n/g' input.txt
```

- `113,$` From line 113 to the end of the file
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/g` Substitute every `PATTERN` with `REPLACEMENT`
- `(.{80})` a group of 80 characters
- `\1` The first captured group

---

Using perl :

```
perl -pe 's/(.{80})(?!$)/\1\n/g if $. > 112' input.txt
```

Comment: @jubilatious1 actually if you take the negative lookahead off, you get a blank line as in the sed option I gave. (if your line is a multiple of 80 char)

Comment: I stand corrected. Updating my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's:g/ (.**80) <?before .> /$0\n/ if ++$ > 3;' 

#OR 

raku -ne '++$ > 3 ?? put S:g/ (.**80) <?before .> /$0\n/ !! .put;' 

#OR 

raku -ne 'if ++$ > 3 {put S:g/ (.**80) <?before .> /$0\n/} else {.put};'  

#OR

raku -e '.put for lines.[^3]; put S:g/ (.**80) <?before .> /$0\n/ for lines();'
```

The above code prints the first three (3) lines of the Sample Input verbatim, then hard-wraps the remaining lines to 80 characters. Lines that are exactly 80 characters remain untouched due to the `<?before .>` positive lookahead (thanks @Marius_Couet!). The OP can adapt this answer to skip wrapping the first 112 lines. Note: words ***will*** be broken using this method.

Sample Input (added exactly 80-character line of `X`s, at line = 6):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
rcitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip e
rcitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip e
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
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
```

Sample Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
rcitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip e
rcitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip e
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdCwgc2Vk
IGRvIGVpdXNtb2QgdGVtcG9yIGluY2lkaWR1bnQgdXQgbGFib3JlIGV0IGRvbG9yZSBtYWduYSBhbGlx
WEuIFV0IGVuaW0gYWQgbWluaW0gdmVuaWFtLCBxdWlzIG5vc3RydWQgZXhlcmNpdGF0aW9uIHVsbGFtY
28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0IGFsaXF1aXAgZXggZWEgY29tbW9kbyBjb25zZXF1YXQuIER1aXMgYXV0Z
SBpcnVyZSBkb2xvciBpbiByZXByZWhlbmRlcml0IGluIHZvbHVwdGF0ZSB2ZWxpdCBlc3NlIGNpbGx1b
SBkb2xvcmUgZXUgZnVnaWF0IG51bGxhIHBhcmlhdHVyLiBFeGNlcHRldXIgc2ludCBvY2NhZWNhdCBjd
XBpZGF0YXQgbm9uIHByb2lkZW50LCBzdW50IGluIGN1bHBhIHF1aSBvZmZpY2lhIGRlc2VydW50IG1vb
GxpdCBhbmltIGlkIGVzdCBsYWJvcnVtLg0KcmNpdGF0aW9uIHVsbGFtY28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0I
GFsaXF1aXAgZQ0KcmNpdGF0aW9uIHVsbGFtY28gbGFib3JpcyBuaXNpIHV0IGFsaXF1aXAgZQ==
```

Please note Raku's `lines.[^3]` idiom ("right-open" range starting from zero) is short for `lines.[0..2]`, i.e. the first 3 lines of the file.

https://docs.raku.org/type/Range
https://raku.org